# Start new record number from 1 when a header appears for a group

Tags: crystal-reports

[image: Image of Crystal Report]

The first column from the left contains a serial number. After the Group Header changes `product name`, I want the serial number to reset to 1 and count up again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Running Total that counts records, then *Resets on Change of Group:* Product Name. This will start at 1 and count up for every record that prints, but resets to 1 whenever the specified group changes.

Comment: I used "Record Number" built in function for the "Serial Number" column which is at the left of the table. i only see my commands while creating a running total, don't have the special fields function there. what should i do?